# How can I send fault on a duplex channel?

Tags: wcf, duplex, fault

A client and a server communicate in duplex mode.
The client has a universal service (Action="*") as contract callback.

I'd like the server to be able to send fault to my client.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

What about setting your Action to something like

```
Action = NotificationData.NotificationAction
```

NotificationData is a MessageContract class that has a property MessageId

```
[MessageContract]
public class NotificationData
{
    public const string NotificationAction = "http://gfader.com/copied-from/tomasz.janczuk.org";

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public DateTime SendTime { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public MessageIds MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

Code on client:
if MessageId == 500 --> error from server

Comment: in fact, my design is a little special. Services are duplex, but clients are Request/Reply and there is a router which translate Request/Reply call in duplex call and vice versa.

So my client must be able to use try{}catch(FaultException<MyFault>){}

Comment: huh... sounds interesting... let us know when you came up with a solution on this!